# applying for jobs?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

When I was in school my teacher taught me to use "apply for" when talking about jobs. So I would say: "I would like to apply for the job as a nurse". However, I came across the sentence "What you must do before applying to jobs". Now I am really confused and cannot find a reliable answer to that question. There is just one explanation that says you´d use "apply to" when you are putting yourself forward as a candidate for something such as a job. The same source also uses the example of "appy for a job". Am I correct in assuming that both versions are possible and that "applying to jobs" is totally fine?

Comment: no, "apply to a job" is wrong

Comment: As this NGram graph shows, "... apply to a job.." is vary uncommon. Looking at actual examples, none apply to this context. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apply+for+a+job%2C+apply+to+a+job&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capply%20for%20a%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capply%20to%20a%20job%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Capply%20for%20a%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capply%20to%20a%20job%3B%2Cc0. You can, for example, "apply to a job posting/listing".

Answer (score 1):

"Apply for" sounds most natural. It is correct when followed by an object, such as "apply for a job."

"Apply to" is more rare, but you might hear it sometimes in situations such as an indirect object ("apply to that company"), or in an infinitive verb ("apply to transfer into the department").